# Accessing the same ParseObject using both Android and JavaScript api

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform

This might sound like a easy question but i'm new to Parse and StackOverFlow. I'm developing an android application which sends a users location to ParseObject as two String values (Latitude and Longitude). I have this working perfectly but I also want to use these two String values in a JavaScript application as well, pulling them in from the same object. So my Question is... Can I access the same ParseObject values using both Android and JavaScript api??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can access the same object. After saving the lat/long to the Parse back end you can pull the data out again using the rest API that parse. provides. The back end in Parse is not limited to a single point of entry. The goal is to have the same data available to as many platforms as possible.

If you have saved your data and it is visible int he parse data browser on their dashboard then you should be able to pull it out again via javascript. Check their javascript developer guide for specifics..

https://parse.com/docs/js_guide

If you need help saving data via Android let me know.